# Entify Framework BulkInsert

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What the best way to bulk inserts a large number of different types of records using UnitOfWork pattern with Entity Framework. I also need to invert back if an error is thrown or something.

I got it working fine using "SqlBulkCopy" but when I wrap this into a transactionscope, I get an error about the connection it is already open using the UnitOfWork.

I can not use EntityFramework.Extensions since it is not open-source.

> Edit - adding Unit Of Work:

Basically, I follow this example: [click here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/825646/Generic-Repository-and-UnitofWork-patterns-in-MVC)

here is my concrete class for unit of work:

```
    public class UnitOfWork<TContext> : Disposable, IUnitOfWork<TContext> where TContext : DbContext, new()
    {

        private  DbContext _context;
        private bool _disposed;

        private IGenericRepository<Log> _logRepository;

        // other generic repositories

        public UnitOfWork()
        {
            _context = new TContext();
        }

        public IGenericRepository<Log> LogRepository 
            => _logRepository ?? (_logRepository = new GenericRepository<Log>(_context));


        //getters for other repositories


        //------------Public Function --------------------------------
        public void Save()
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        // this is the bulkInsert using SqlBulkCopy 
        //but getting error on the transactionscope due to opening a new connection
        public virtual void BulkInsert<T>(DbContextTransaction tx, string tableName, System.Data.DataTable dataTable)
        {
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(dataTable.TableName, @"^[A-Za-z0-9\._]+$"))
            {
                return;
            }

            SqlTransaction sqlTx = (SqlTransaction)tx?.UnderlyingTransaction;

            var columnNames =
                _context.Database.SqlQuery<SysColumns>("SELECT c.Name, t.name as Type FROM sys.columns c JOIN sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('" + dataTable.TableName + "')");

            if (columnNames == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var connectionString = _context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, sqlTx))
                {
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = (int) TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalSeconds;

                    foreach (var column in dataTable.Columns)
                    {
                        var dbColumn =
                                columnNames.FirstOrDefault(x => string.Equals(x.Name, column.ToString(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

                        if (dbColumn != null)
                        {
                            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), dbColumn.Name);
                        }
                    }

                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        private void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    _context.Dispose();
                }
            }
            _disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

    }
}
```

> Edit - Add More code:

```
    public void ProcessData()
    {

        using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
        {
            try
            {
                _repository.LogRepository.Insert(//log to initial import data)

                ImportData(); 

               _repository.LogRepository.Insert(//log to Complete import data)
                _repository.Save();                   
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                transaction.Dispose();

            }
        }
    }

     private void ImportData()
    {
        //Creating object of datatable  
        var tblcsv =
            new DataTable("dbo.Table") { CaseSensitive = false };

        //getting full file path of Uploaded file  
        var csvFilePath = _dataImportModel.RootPath + "\\Collector\\" + "data.csv";

        //Reading All text  
        var readCsv = File.ReadAllText(csvFilePath);

        foreach (var csvRow in readCsv.Split('\n'))
        {
                foreach (var fileColumn in csvRow.Split(','))
                {
                    tblcsv.Columns.Add(fileColumn);
                }
                break;

        }

        //spliting row after new line  
        var rows = readCsv.Split('\n');
        foreach (var csvRow in rows)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(csvRow))
            {

                var count = 0;
                var columnsData = SplitCsv(csvRow);

                    //Adding each row into datatable  
                    tblcsv.Rows.Add();
                    foreach (var fileRec in columnsData)
                    {
                        tblcsv.Rows[tblcsv.Rows.Count - 1][count] =
                            string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileRec) ? null : fileRec;
                        count++;
                    }

            }
        }

        _repository.BulkInsert<DataTable>(null,  "dbo.Table", tblcsv);
    }
```

Comment: please show your UoW implementation

Comment: @solidau edited my question let me know if you need more

Comment: 'I get an error about the connection it is already open', on which line exactly you get this error? Using the code you provided, it looks you open a new connection, so I doubt the error happens here.

Comment: @JonathanMagnan add more code: i get the error inside the BulkInsert at line connection.Open();

Comment: The only thing I can come up with, and its a long-shot, is you're getting a race condition.  Can you humor me for a minute and add a `lock(....)` around your bulk insert method and see if the problem still occurs?

Comment: Could you parse the exact error? Perhaps that will give us a hint about what's really hapenning

Comment: @JonathanMagnan I looked at inner exception, error message is "The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D025)". I don't have access to the SQL server to enable DTC, is there a way around this?

Comment: @JonathanMagnan, just wondering how come it work if i don't call the bulkinsert?

Comment: Now we have the real error ;) So if I understand, you are using a TransactionScope. Something, perhaps the _repository.LogRepository insert stuff in the Server A, and the ImportData method insert rows in the Server B? Which leads to this error since you insert in two different servers. Some other possible cause may lead to this error as well.

Comment: @JonathanMagnan It is the same server/Database

Comment: The only reason i am using TransactionScope is if something fail/throws an error, from my understanding TransactionScope will reverse change in sql to before. If there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: @Valter, I have added an answer to add some code since it will make easier to show some examples of possible cause than the comment section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I looked at inner exception, error message is "The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D025)

There is a lot of possible causes why this issue can happen.

By example, opening a connection than another connection without closing the first one can lead tot this kind of error:

```
using (var context = new CurrentContext())
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        context.Database.Connection.Open();
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT 1", connection))
            {
                var x = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

    }      
}
```

Comment: basically what I did was dispose the context before insertBulk and re-create the context after. That fix my issue.

Comment: That's great ;) By the way, I'm the owner the the Z.EntityFramework.Extensions library, so if you need more help to implement it, don't be shy to ask me directly

Comment: I used it and works great with the trial version... I ask my manager if we could get a license but I don't know if we will get it. But it is a great product.